# Insert comma into digits and decimal number with regex

Tags: regex

I saw many posts to insert comma into just digits or decimal numbers, but not both, so let me ask here.

```
1234 -> 1,234
1234567 -> 12,34,567
123 -> 123
1234.123 -> 1,234.123
0.123 -> 0.123
0.12345 -> 0.12345
```

I wanna insert comma like this using regex but I cannot make one which support both digits and decimal numbers.

I tried these but didnt work....

```
/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+)/
/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))\.?\d*/
```

Any idea to make it work?

Comment: Why a regex? Why not something programmatic that would be a lot simpler? Split on the `.` (if any), format the first item with comma-separated digit triples, and rejoin.

Comment: What is your regex flavor? e.g. Javascript/python/Java/Perl/PHP/.NET ?

Comment: preferably JS or Java

Comment: regex is more concise and more flexible IMO

Comment: [This solution](https://regex101.com/r/H9gi6i/1) works on PHP/perl/PCRE

Comment: wow that's cool and concise but im not familiar with PHP but I'll find out! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in Javascript (modern Javascript supports lookbehind):

```bash
(?<!\.\d*)(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\.\d*)`: Negative lookbehind to assert that we don't have a decimal point before current position
- `(\d)`: Match a digit and capture in group #1
- `(?=`: Start Lookahead

  - `(?:\d{3})+`: Make sure we have 1 or more sets of 3 digits ahead
  - `(?:\.|$)`: that is followed by a dot or end of line
- `)`: End Lookahead

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/H9gi6i/2)

Or if you're on PCRE then use:

```bash
\.\d+$(*SKIP)(*F)|(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/H9gi6i/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex with substitution

```
(?=(?<!\.)(?!^)\d{3}(?:\b|(?:\d{3})+)\b)
```

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NRaHx9/1)

##### JavaScript Example

```js
function format(string) {
  let pattern = /(?=(?!^)\d{3}(?:\b|(?:\d{3})+)\b)/g;
  if (string.includes('.')) {
    pattern = /(?=(?!^)\d{3}(?:\b|(?:\d{3})+)\b\.)/g;
  }
  return string.replace(pattern, ',');
}

console.log('1234', '->', format('1234'));
console.log('123', '->', format('123'));
console.log('1234.123', '->', format('1234.123'));
console.log('0.123', '->', format('0.123'));
console.log('12345642.234234', '->', format('12345642.234234'));
```